# How to find the critical numbers of a trig function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So here's my function: $g(θ) = 20θ − 5 tan θ$

The instructions are: Find the critical numbers of the function. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. Use $n$ to denote any arbitrary integer values. If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)

I managed to get the derivative to be: $20 - 5sec^2\theta$ and I managed to get to $sec \theta = 2$ but I'm stuck here. Can someone please help me?

Comment: When you say "critical numbers" do you, perhaps, means either *critical points* or *critical values*? Critical points are the $\theta$ for which $\mathrm{g}'(\theta)=0$ while critical values are the values that $\mathrm{g}$ takes at critical points, i.e. $\mathrm{g}(\theta)$.

Comment: I have the strange feeling that you are doing a problem on WebAssign.  Please read [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353) on meta.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $sec^2\theta = 4$ means that $sec\theta$ can be $2$ or $-2$.

$sec\theta = \pm2 \implies cos\theta = \pm\tfrac{1}{2}$.

For what values of $\theta$ does $cos\theta = \tfrac{1}{2}$ or $\tfrac{-1}{2}$?

Well, there are an infinite number of them, but we can reduce all of them to four common forms:

- $2\pi n + \dfrac{\pi}{3}$
- $2\pi n + \dfrac{2\pi}{3}$
- $2\pi n + \dfrac{4\pi}{3}$
- $2\pi n + \dfrac{5\pi}{3}$

This is all for some integer $n$. We get this because $2\pi n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a full rotation around the circle, so the angle is the same. And the four points $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3}, \dfrac{2\pi}{3}, \dfrac{4\pi}{3}, \dfrac{5\pi}{3}$ are the four points in the range $[0 ,2\pi )$ where $cos\theta = \pm\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Would it be pi/3 * 2n?

Comment: @user136125 You're on the right track. I edited in the answer so you can see how it's done. :)

Comment: Thank you so much man. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user136125 You are very welcome. :)